# Typescript class is throwing type errors because properties not declared

Tags: typescript

New to typescript; I'm creating a new class that accepts an object as as a parameter, so it can use all of its methods; while adapting a method to update a value; as shown in the docs: https://www.twilio.com/docs/openapi/mock-api-generation-with-twilio-openapi-spec

I'm getting errors because the methods from the original class are not declared in this new class; is there a way to declare them, remove the errors, without changing their functionality?

The RequestClient has the types, but my new class does not.

code:

```
import { PrismClient } from './PrismClient';

// const client = new twilio.Twilio(accountSid, authToken);

const client = new twilio.Twilio(accountSid, authToken, {
  httpClient: new PrismClient('http://prism:4010', new twilio.RequestClient()),
});
```

ERRORS: Type 'PrismClient' is missing the following properties from type 'RequestClient': axios, autoRetry, maxRetryDelay, maxRetries, and 2 more.

```
export class PrismClient {
  constructor(
    public prismUrl,
    public requestClient,
  ) {
    this.prismUrl = prismUrl;
    this.requestClient = requestClient;
  }

  request(opts) {
    opts.uri = opts.uri.replace(/^https\:\/\/.*?\.twilio\.com/, this.prismUrl);
    return this.requestClient.request(opts);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs shown are using Javascript. The only way to know that the minimum required properties for an override is `request` is by trusting that the demo code is valid.

Since you're using Typescript, you have to conform to the type of the function's arguments. If Twilio has poor type interfacing, that's an issue on their side (that you can bring up as a Github issue for instance).

### Approach 1: inheritance

Make your `PrismClient` extend from [`RequestClient`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/src/base/RequestClient.ts):

```
class PrismClient extends from twilio.RequestClient {
  // [...]
}
```

Then you'll override the methods to delegate to your `requestClient` property:

```
override request<TData>(
    opts: RequestClient.RequestOptions<TData>
): Promise<Response<TData>> {
    opts.uri = opts.uri.replace(/^https\:\/\/.*?\.twilio\.com/, this.prismUrl);
    return this.requestClient.request<TData>(opts);
}

override filterLoggingHeaders(headers: Headers) {
    return this.requestClient.filterLoggingHeaders(headers);
}

// Sadly you can't override `logRequest` since it's private (and not protected or public)
```

To make this even cleaner you should delegate the properties of the base class to your `requestClient` property. Sadly, [Typescript doesn't allow overriding properties with accessors](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/37894#issuecomment-862533228), so there's no easy way of syncing them. But you should be fine, since all other methods delegate to `requestClient`.

### Approach 2: composition

Do the exact same thing, but without extending the class from `twilio.RequestClient`. This should allow you to "override" properties with accessors to delegate getters and setters to `requestClient`'s properties.

These are the properties you have to expose:

```
defaultTimeout: number;
axios: AxiosInstance;
lastResponse?: Response<any>;
lastRequest?: Request<any>;
autoRetry: boolean;
maxRetryDelay: number;
maxRetries: number;
```

For instance, with `defaultTimeout`:

```
get defaultTimeout(): number {
    return this.requestClient.defaultTimeout;
}

set defaultTimeout(value: number) {
    this.requestClient.defaultTimeout = value;
}
```

If typescript accepts that code despite not being an actual instance of `twilio.RequestClient`, then you should be A-OK.

Comment: Thanks Vivick, I did figure it out by using inheritance. Thank you for introducing me to override, get and set.